# screen black out and window resume after power on

Tags: windows, display

My laptop screen turns black sometimes automatically and will not power up until manually done. after power up windows start to resume all the processes that were running. and this process once started keep on continuing until laptop is force shut down and start up again.
what may be the reasons for that?

Answer (score 1):

The screen turning off, from your symptoms, is the machine going into one of hibernate, sleep or standby power states...

The resume loop is most probably the hibernate (or other "state-saving") file being corrupt - forcing you to power cycle the computer. Although Windows 8 actually uses a hybrid hibernate/shutdown (when you call "shutdown") I wouldn't recommend always hibernating your machine - for this very reason. Turn off hibernate and sleep; if you're not going to use it for a few hours why not properly shutdown? If you're only going for a short time then lock the machine and have only the display turn off after a few minutes of inactivity...

Are you concerned about power consumption?